# Get the hundredths place value digit in a double variable using java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the digit in the hundredth's place of a double value (second digit after the decimal).

So, for example, if the double value is 48.4569999, I want to get the value **5** using any Math or BigDecimal methods, which is the hundredth's place after decimal.

I have tried the following code:

```
BigDecimal src = new BigDecimal("48.4569999");
BigDecimal a = src.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
System.out.println("a : " + a);
```

which results in .456999 but I dont want to use any String functions to get to the second digit. Is there any Math or Bigdecimal function to do this please ? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What about multiply by 100, then take the integer part and take remainder after dividing by 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `movePointRight(int)`.

```
int a = src.movePointRight(2).remainder(BigDecimal.TEN).intValue();
```

prints

> a : 5

Comment: Perfect, very elegant solution, thank you.....Knew BigDecimal class was very powerful but starting to realize it now !!!

Answer (score 5):

Why not multiply by 100, to push your desired value to the right place, cast to int (to remove anything < 1) and then do % 10, which will give you the remainder (which will be your desired digit).

Comment: was trying this solution until I found the one with BigDecimal. This works too but the BigDecimal one was more easier to implement...Thank you, nevertheless for the help !!!

Comment: Nice one, true. Haven't used BigDecimal myself much, so I learned something good, too ;-)